# Google Cloud/BigQuery: Is there a way to make sure that each query that runs. runs on the correct project for billing purposes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, billing

I have an organisation on BigQuery and I have multiple projects there. I wanted to do an analysis on my billing exports and found out that some queries that used "FROM project1" were being billed under "project2" for example. Does anyone know a way to make sure that each query (scheduled or not) will be billed under the right project-id?

I tried contacting Google Cloud Support, but they haven't reached out to me with a solution (yet). I have looked through all the bigquery settings but haven't got a clue.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery has a typical billing mode that separate the compute and the storage.

- The data can be stored in a project and the project pay for that storage cost
- The data can be requested from a project and the processing cost are set on that project.

With that context, there is no technical problem to have data in a project1 and to query them from Project2. You can't block that with BigQuery.

You have to ensure that the permissions are correct (especially for service account to be sure that the service account of project2 can't read the data of project1), or even deactivate the APIs on a project

---

However, if you have access to project1 and project2, and you can run query jobs in the 2 projects, and the BigQuery API are activated in the 2 projects, you can do nothing to prevent that mistake

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So unfortunately, I have queries that run on both projects every 5 minutes. I just dont understand why some of the data that is queried in project1 is stored in project2. Is this a BigQuery mistake, or is it possible for me to allocate each query to the correct project

Comment: No, I can confirm you that's not a BigQuery mistake. If there is a mistake, it's in the query job configuration. Review what is done, and I'm sure you will find an issue in it. But it could be not an issue also! Maybe project1 need project2's data to join them and work with them!